# Dynamically nest key value in HashMap with object as value

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a requirement to nest a key-value in an existing key value pair of a HashMap.
my current output as json is

```
...
    "x": {
      "y": yhyhy,
      "z": "zhzhz",
      "d": 123
    }
...
```

I want to add a new pair as follows:

```
...
    "x": {
      "y": yhyhy,
      "z": "zhzhz",
      "d": 123,
      "k": "khkhkh"
    }
..
```

The issue with achieving this is : the hashmap prepared initially is by inserting an entire object as value (reposneObject is an immutableMap being used elsewhere)

```
Map<Object, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>(responseObject);
                    responseMap.put("x", someObject);
```

I do not want to separately insert each field of the someObject into the map (as the count can be huge)
Is there any other way of doing it using maps or something? (dynamically adding a field in an object doesn't seem possible)

Comment: Is that what you need?  `responseMap.get("x").put("k": "khkhkh");` assuming `someObject` is a `Map`

Comment: are "y", "z" and "d" keys of responseObject and you wan't to add "k" and all other fields from someObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `someObject` is a Map:

```
Map<Object, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>(responseObject);
responseMap.put("x", someObject);
responseMap.get("x").put("k": "khkhkh");
```

Comment: Converting someObject to a Map was the answer using objectWrapper. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way of doing it using maps or something?

`responseMap.putAll(someObject);` where someObject is a [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll(java.util.Map)).